# Gimp won't allow me to copy and paste a transparent image

Tags: windows-7, gimp, transparency

On the latest version of GIMP on my PC, whenever I try to copy a transparent image from the internet, GIMP will automatically fill in the transparent areas with the background color I have selected.

This is a non-issue on my Mac, but I need to do this work on my PC, so how can I make it recognize the alpha of the image and not fill it with the background color?

The image canvas that I'm working with **does** have an alpha channel, but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on why this is a bad question? It is a legitimate question that I have researched and cannot find the answer to.

Comment: What is the source picture format?

Comment: @NelsonChan png with transparency

Comment: How are you 'copying' them?  Right click save as?  That's the only way I can think of that will retain the alpha channel.  Print screen or Snipping Tool won't.

Comment: @NelsonChan Right click and "Copy Image"

Comment: try downloading the image with right click- save as. If that doesn't work, something weird that I've noticed is that re-sizing the image, even by one pixle, magically makes the background transparent again.

Comment: Copying the Wikipedia PNG example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#mediaviewer/File:PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png from Firefox to GIMP in any way I can think of works for me on Windows 7. 

David, this is the GIMP 2.8.14 from download.gimp.org?

Comment: Just gave up and drew the damn image. Gimp really needs to fix counterintuitive stuff such as "gimp tries to paste a transparency as opaque over another image" nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

This "works for me" - actually the only I see of it not working is if one does `edit->paste` on GIMP - it them creates a "floating selection" - which is a temporary layer which exists mostly to allow positioning of the pasted contents - and them  "anchor" the floating layer on a opaque, background layer. The transparency was there, as expected, but "anchoring" is the act of fixing the pasted pixels on the background. Note that just clicking on the image, outside the selection will anchor the pasted data in this way.

The options you have are either, after `edit->paste` click on the `New Layer` button (frst button on the layers dialog - or through the `Layer->New Layer` (`Shift + Ctrl + N`) menu action: this will promote the pasted contents to a full layer which retains its transparency. Or, you might as well just paste with `Edit->Paste As->New Layer` to start with: no floating selection is created.

Comment: Anchoring on a transparent (background) layer preserves the transparency, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The data saved to the clipboard when copying the photo may not support the aplha channel/transparent data. What works for me is opening the transparent picture in GIMP, then clicking and dragging the layer from the transparent image into the project I'm working on. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Gimp one image was pasted to another as a black-white. A transparency and colors have been lost. So I turned off a visibility of other layers, selected a needed layer and copied whole image to a new one. Then cropped.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**
I couldnt find a way to make it paste with the transparent background. Luckily, the background I needed to paste it on is white, so I just opened an excel spreadsheet and merged a bunch of cells to make a white background, pasted my image, then used the snipping tool to select my image then pasted into GIMP

Answer (score 0):

Classic mistake is to assume the picture you want to "Paste as New Layer" is actually transparent. (The white-gray background is no guarantee.) Most of the people here who ask this question do not realize that they are trying to paste non transparent picture. If the background in your pic is truly (alpha) transparent it will immidiatelly show on the new pic without the "white-grey" background. If it pastes with the white-grey background then it's not and you are doing something wrong. It's the actual source image that is the problem.

Try this. Using your mouse right click a source (google searched transparent) image on your browser and paste that directly to GNU GIMP as a new layer... and voila. You most likely succeed with first try. There is no need to try to save the source to your hard drive (correctly or incorrectly).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it pastes the transparency as well. Argh. I don't understand why gimp would ever try to paste a transparency, like what sense does that actually make?